# For Tokensregex, does a rule need to be token type to use Annotate?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am going over some older code Tokensregex code and I am faced with a situation where some characters are not being tokenized by the PTBTokenizer.  In particular, I am looking at currency symbols.  So for example, ₱ would not be a token whereas some others are such as $ would.

Well I want to try to write a text type rule instead of token type to try to catch this symbol otherwise in a capture group and then do something like `Annotate($0, ner, "MONEY")` to capture a string such as ₱240.

When I attempt this I get:

> ... 49 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.String   at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.SequenceMatchRules$TextPatternExtractRuleCreator.create(SequenceMatchRules.java:666)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.SequenceMatchRules.createExtractionRule(SequenceMatchRules.java:331)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.SequenceMatchRules.createRule(SequenceMatchRules.java:321)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.Rule(TokenSequenceParser.java:141)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.RuleList(TokenSequenceParser.java:125)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.parser.TokenSequenceParser.updateExpressionExtractor(TokenSequenceParser.java:32)
>     at
>   edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:292)
>     ... 52 more

So can I do the above, create a MONEY ner annotation. if the currency symbol is missed by the tokenizer?

**EXAMPLE**

Text rule attempt at doing what I want (create ner annotation called CURRENCY for a string containing a peso monetary value)

```
ENV.defaults["ruleType"] = "text"
{ text: /(₱\d+)/ => Annotate($0, ner, "CURRENCY")}
```

Token rule successfully doing what I want (because yen is a recoginized token).  This creates a yen monetary string with ner annotation of CURRENCY.

```
ENV.defaults["ruleType"] = "tokens"
ENV.defaults["matchWithResults"] = TRUE

# Set default string pattern flags (to case-insensitive)
ENV.defaultStringPatternFlags = 2

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 0

# Ex: ¥3000
{   
pattern:  ([{ word: "¥" }] $NUMBER_COMMA_SEP $LARGE_NUMBERS?),
action: (Annotate($0, ner, "CURRENCY"))
}
```

ner is defined as:

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
```

and then:

```
$NUMBER_COMMA_SEP = "$NUMBER_NON_CD | ([{ tag: /CD/ } & $VALID_NUMERIC_CHARS] [{ tag: /CD/; word: /,\d+(\.\d+)?/ }]*)"
$LARGE_NUMBERS = "/thousand|million|mil|mn|billion|bil|bn|trillion/"
```

Comment: Could you please post the full rules file you are trying to use.

Comment: I don't think I am able to do that, but I will include greater examples in my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the tokenizer is not deleting untokenizable tokens.

command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,tokensregex -tokensregex.rules example-rules.txt -props StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties -tokenize.options "untokenizable=allKeep" -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

example-rules.txt

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

{ pattern: ( /₱/ /[0-9]+/ ) , action: (Annotate($0, ner, "CURRENCY") ) }
```

If you run on text with that symbol with the tokenizer configured properly it will create a distinct token for that symbol.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought.  No token, no ner annotation generated.  I will try the `allKeep` option (and any other options above I might not be using) when I run the tokensregex for my rules file and report back.

Comment: By the way, I checked and I saw before I had been using `noneDelete` for untokenizable.

Comment: Yes that worked well, thanks.  I have to analyze though what the tradeoff is as this is part of a pipeline.  I think there was some reason a long time ago why we wanted to throwaway those untokenizables.